# Запятая или тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в этом предложении? Знаю, что если перед сказуемым, выраженным сущ. в им.п. есть "не", то тире не ставится. напр. "Бедность не порок". Но распространяется ли это правило на этот случай?

"А т.к. мы не являлись владельцами – мы не могли оборудовать их по своему усмотрению".

Или лучше: "А т.к. мы не являлись владельцами, то не могли оборудовать их по своему усмотрению".

Изначально было: "А т.к. мы не являлись владельцами, не могли оборудовать их по своему усмотрению".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначальный вариант "А т.к. мы не являлись владельцами, не могли оборудовать их по своему усмотрению"  неудачен, так как в нем не выражена причинно-следственная связь сказуемых.
Два остальных варианта можно использовать.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Чтобы выразить причинно-следственную связь, требуется двухместный союз ТАК КАК...ТО. Если вторая часть союза пропущена, то ставится тире.